# add multiple include path

Tags: path, include

I try to use the following command to add path "/opt/my/include" for searching .h files:

(for C program)

```
 $ C_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/my/include 
 $ export C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

(for C++ program)

```
 $ CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/my/include 
 $ export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Then use command:

```
 $ cpp -Iheaders -v
```

to check the results.

I can add an include path successfully, the problem is when I try to add another include path in the same manner, the previous path will be overwritten.
Can I add multiple include paths valid for all the program permanently?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

different path can be assigned to the same variable by appending. Different values are separated by colon.
e.g. suppose I want to export /path1 and /path2, the command should be:

```
$ PATH=/path1:/path2
$ export PATH
```

or simply:

```
$ export PATH=/path1:/path2
```

If the variable PATH already has other value(s) and you do not want to overwrite them, we can append the original value(s) at the end:

```
$export PATH=/path1:/path2:$PATH
```

where the $ sign means take the value(s).